# Definition for monotonicity of multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is there any standard definition for monotonicity of a multivariate function?

I suppose it's something like:

> $\forall i: x_i \leq x_i' \implies f(x_1, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_k) \leq f(x_1, \ldots, x_i', \ldots, x_k)$

thanks!

Comment: Can you actually clarify where the $\forall$ is being applied in your definition? I don't think it captures what should be intuitively monotone.

Comment: Should there be primes on $x_1$ and $x_k$ on the right hand side? If so, our definitions agree.

Comment: no, no primes, just 1 larger argument..

Comment: I think in terms of monotonicity, my definition is more standard. I don't know what else you would like to know here.

Answer (score 4):

A sensible extension of monotonicity is the following. Let $A$ and
$B$ be partially ordered sets. Let $f\colon A\rightarrow B$. $f$
is monotone if for each $x,y\in A$ s.t. $x\leq y$ we have that $f\left(x\right)\leq f\left(y\right)$.
Just take $A=\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $B=\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for the case you are interested in.

Comment: But this would require the $\leq$ relation to be defined on tuples from A and on those from B?

Comment: We can easily define the partial ordering by: $\mathbf{x} \leq \mathbf{y}$ if $\forall n : x_n \leq y_n$

Comment: With that the definition of @par is equivalent to your definition, Xaero182, since it follows from applying your definition multiple times on different $x_n$.